# How do wizards learn new spells in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

I believe that they make their wand learn the spell but what happens if a graduated wizard loses his wand? Would he basically have lost all what he studied for during his stay at Hogwarts?

Also, imagine that a first grader gets a hold of a list with all the known spells, what stops them from going bonkers and casting all of them as if they were a really powerful wizard?

Comment: Makes me wonder if you have actually read the books …

Comment: Not really, it's mostly second hand knowledge, I mainly follow Star Wars lore but my sister does follow Harry Potter and that made me curious about the above points.

Comment: From the dupe: "*There was a lot more to magic, as Harry quickly found out, than waving your wand and saying a few funny words."*